# htaccess redirect rules, main folder and subfolders redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

Story: I'm developing a website which has three sub folders in the main directory as /a/, /b/ and /c/. Contents in site.com, site.com/a/, site.com/b/ and site.com/c/ are different; however, the codes and files are completely similar. In order to reduce the volume of the codes, I used the following .htaccess rule and deleted the similar codes in /a/, /b/ and /c/ subfolders:

```
RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Everything works fine, but below is the only problem.
Problem: I have a search button in the menu bar of all four pages (i.e. `site.com`, `site.com/a/`, `site.com/b/` and `site.com/c/`). When I search a sentence like "hello world" in the subfolder pages (i.e. `site.com/a/`, `site.com/b/` and `site.com/c/`), the results return in the following format:
`site.com/hello-world/?folder=a`
`site.com/hello-world/?folder=b`
`site.com/hello-world/?folder=c`
But, above search results must return in the below format instead:
`site.com/a/hello-world/`
`site.com/b/hello-world/`
`site.com/c/hello-world/`
Is there any `.htaccess` rule to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule to 301 redirect `site.com/hello-world/?folder=c` => `site.com/a/hello-world/`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)\?folder=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Just make sure this is placed **before your existing rule**

Comment: thanks for your answer,I tried your code before the existing rule, and still no luck.

Comment: Sorry had a typo, just fixed it. Try again.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, worked fine. again I appreciate you. cheers

Comment: Glad to know, can you now mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix the issue in .htaccess. You need to fix your application so that it generates correct URLs for the search results. Currently it is using the current page URL when generating search results, and that is why you get results like that.

Comment: before I deleted the similar codes in /a/, /b/ and /c/ sufolders, the results were returned in the right format like  site.com/a/hello-world/ site.com/b/hello-world/ site.com/c/hello-world/.

Comment: Well, in that case I think Apache didn't use the redirect rule, because the files were already available. The problem is in the actual code that generates the search results, take a look at it.